# Kaplan-Meier estimator when no censoring

Tags: self-study, survival, censoring, kaplan-meier

I am looking at the Kaplan-Meier estimator of the survival function when we have no censored observations. Let $$\hat{S}(t) =\begin{cases} 1,&\quad t<t_1, \\
 \prod_{t_i\le t}[1-\frac{d_i}{Y_i}],&\quad t_1\le t\end{cases},$$
where $t_1<t_2<...<t_D$ are our observed failure times, $d_i$ is the number of events at time $t_i$ and $Y_i$ is the risk set at time $t_i$. We then assume there are no censored observations. It is then stated that the Kaplan-Meier estimator is equal to $1-\hat{F}$ where $\hat{F}$ is the empirical distribution function: $\hat{F}(t)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n1_{[0,t]}(X_i)$.

I have been tried to show this myself and this is what I have got: Since there are no censored observations we have $$d_i=\sum_{j=1}^n1_{X_j=t_i},Y_i=\sum_{j=1}^n1_{X_j\ge t_i}.$$Hence $$1-\frac{d_i}{Y_i}=\frac{Y_i-d_i}{Y_i}=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^n1_{X_j>t_i}}{Y_i}.$$
Note also that $$1-\hat{F}(t_i)=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^n1_{X_j>t_i}}{n}.$$

However I´m kinda stuck here and could use some help. Thank you for your time.

Comment: If there are no censorings, then why not just resort to empirical survival function?

Comment: The point is to show that the Kaplan-Meier estimator is the empirical survival function when there are no censored observations, hence we can just use that.

Comment: Try to carry through the scenario of no tied observations: $Z_{(1) } < Z_{(2) } < \cdots < Z_{(n) }.$ Then KM estimate is $$\hat{S}(t) = \prod_{j: Z_{(j) }  \leq t}\left(\frac{n-j}{n-j+1}\right) ^{\delta_{(j) }};$$ for no censoring, $\delta_{(j) }= 1.$ Expand the product. See what happens.